# Recursive generic type to extend types - weird behaviour, is this a bug?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, typescript-types

Given an interface

```
interface Test {
  inner: {
    value: boolean,
  }
}
```

and a class

```
class ContextualData<T> {
   constructor(public data: T) {}
}
```

I would like to be able to do as such:

```
const original: Test = {
  inner: {
    value: true,
  },
}

// Wrap the value in a ContextualData object.
original.inner.value = new ContextualData<boolean>(original.inner.value)
```

Which I'm trying to achieve by declaring the following types:

```
export type Primitive = undefined | null | boolean | string | number | Function

export type Contextuable<T> = T | ContextualData<T>

export type DeepContextuable<T> =
  T extends Primitive ? Contextuable<T> : DeepContextuableObject<T>

export type DeepContextuableObject<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: DeepContextuable<T[K]>
}
```

and then using `DeepContextual` to transform my `Test` interface:

```
const original: DeepContextual<Test> = {
  inner: {
    value: new ContextualData<boolean>(true),
  },
}
```

This works fine.

Now, let's add another method to our `ContextualData` class:

```
class ContextualData<T> {
   constructor(public data: T) {}

   public map<U>(mapFn: (current: T) => U): U {
     return mapFn(this.data)
   }
}
```

Even without using the new function, our Contextual interface with `value: ContextualData<boolean>(true)` now throws the following TS error:

```
TS2322: Type 'ContextualData<boolean>' is not assignable to type 
'boolean | ContextualData<true> | ContextualData<false>'.
```

What am I missing? Is this a bug?

Comment: I think you're running up against this: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types ... your example works if you're dealing with a `string` because that is truly a primitive type, but since `boolean` is really a union type for `true | false`, the conditional type is distributing it to an entire variant of either type `true` or `false`.  So if you change it to a `ContextualData<true>(true)` it would also work (and the `Test` type's inner value would also have to be type `true`).  I played with it, but found no fix for `boolean`

Answer (score 1):

You have run into the distributive behavior of conditional types. This (very useful) behavior dictates that a conditional type distributes over the union members of a naked type parameter. Pair this with the fact that Typescript sees `boolean` as `true | false` as and we get that.

```
DeepContextuable<boolean> = DeepContextuable<true | false>  
   = DeepContextuable<true> | DeepContextuable<false>  
   = (true | Contextuable<true>) | (false | Contextuable<false>)
   = boolean | Contextuable<true> |  Contextuable<false
```

This behavior only occurs over naked type parameters. To disable it we can put the parameter in a tuple and things will work as you expected them to.

```
export type Primitive = undefined | null | boolean | string | number | Function

export type Contextuable<T> = T | ContextualData<T>

export type DeepContextuable<T> =
[T] extends [Primitive] ? Contextuable<T> : DeepContextuableObject<T>

export type DeepContextuableObject<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: DeepContextuable<T[K]>
}

interface Test {
    inner: {
        value: boolean,
    }
}

class ContextualData<T> {
    constructor(public data: T) { }

    public map<U>(mapFn: (current: T) => U): U {
        return mapFn(this.data)
    }
}

const original: DeepContextuable<Test> = {
    inner: {
        value: new ContextualData<boolean>(true),
    },
}
```